# running Docker nginx cannot find copied files

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, docker-compose

i have a simple nginx Dockerfile which copies local letsencrypt files when building the image

```
FROM nginx

COPY fullchain.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/engi.network/fullchain.pem;

COPY privkey.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/engi.network/privkey.pem;

COPY options-ssl-nginx.conf /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

COPY ssl-dhparams.pem /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

COPY default.conf.template /etc/nginx/templates/default.conf.template

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
```

however when I run the Dockerfile using compose, I am getting the error `[emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:30`

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if this path already exist in nginx image

`/etc/letsencrypt/live/engi.network`.

First create these paths using

`RUN mkdir -p /etc/letsencrypt/live/engi.network/`

command

Comment: oh, i assumed `COPY` would create (like `mkdir -p`) paths that don't exists

Comment: that didn't seem to do it

Comment: i am running the build command from within the context of all of these files as well (https://serverfault.com/questions/666149/docker-copy-issue-no-such-file-or-directory). ./fullchain.pem ./options-ssl-nginx.conf are direct children of the dir i run the build command from

Comment: once files are copied successfully, check permissions on them. If nginx is aloowed to read them.